# Django Rest Framework and MongoDB - listField does not works It returns None when object is embedded

Tags: mongodb, django-rest-framework, listfield, djongo

I'm using MongoDB the connection is provided by Djongo, over is being used DRF to manage all request to mi API.

My data (profile) is structured like this

```
{
    "name" : "profile name",
    "description" : "this is a description",
    "params" : "X1, X2,X3, etc",
    "config" : "CONFIG OF DEVICE",
    "user" : {
        "name" : "user name",
        "middle_name" : "test middle name",
        "last_name" : "test last name",
        "email" : "test@test.com",
        "institute" : {
            "name" : "MIT",
            "place" : {
                "coordinates" : [ 30.0, 101.0,  0.0 ],
                "type" : "Point"
            },
            "country" : "US"
        }
    },
    "place" : {
        "coordinates" : [  90.0, 901.0, 10.0 ],
        "type" : "Point"
    },
    "devices" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "DEVICE 1",
            "verification_code" : "",
            "verificated" : 0,
            "configuration" : "kjk",
            "places" : [ 
                {
                    "coordinates" : [ 30.0,  101.0,  0.0 ],
                    "type" : "Point"
                }, 
                {
                    "coordinates" : [  31.0, 102.0, 1.0 ],
                    "type" : "Point"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I know, the coordinates are wrong, but is just for test.

Well I send that object to my view and then to the ProfileSerializer, this get the responsible to check the embedded objects (each one have your own serializer). After checking data, the info is saved without problem as you can see in next picture:

[image: Screenshot 2019-03-21 at 14 44 05]

But the problem is when I try to. retrieve all profiles. Just the coordinates are null, Other embedded objects are retrieved in good way, only the Place Object is malformed. Next, I'll show you the response:

```
[
{
        "id": 22,
        "name": "profile name",
        "description": "this is a description",
        "params": "X1, X2,X3, etc",
        "config": "CONFIG OF DEVICE",
        "user": {
            "name": "user name",
            "middle_name": "test middle name",
            "last_name": "test last name",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "institute": {
                "name": "MIT",
                "place": {
                    "coordinates": **null**,
                    "type": "Point"
                },
                "country": "US",
                "created_at": "2019-03-21T20:43:33.928000Z"
            },
            "created_at": "2019-03-21T20:43:33.959000Z"
        },
        "place": {
            "coordinates": **null**,
            "type": "Point"
        },
        "devices": [
            {
                "name": "DEVICE 1",
                "verificated": 0,
                "configuration": "kjk",
                "places": [
                    {
                        "coordinates": **null**,
                        "type": "Point"
                    },
                    {
                        "coordinates": **null**,
                        "type": "Point"
                    }
                ],
                "created_at": "2019-03-21T20:43:33.898000Z"
            }
        ],
        "created_at": "2019-03-21T20:43:33.976000Z"
    }
]
```

For this questions only I'll describe/show the serializer  of one  object, but if you need some info I'll get you as soon as possible.

Models

```
class Place(models.Model):
    coordinates = models.ListField(blank=True, null=True, default=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="Point")
    objects = models.DjongoManager()

class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(default="Without Description")
    params = models.TextField(default="No params")
    config = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=User
    )
    place = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=Place
    )
    devices = models.ArrayModelField(
        model_container=Device
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.DjongoManager()
```

Serializers

```
class PlaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    coordinates = serializers.ListSerializer(
        child=serializers.FloatField(),
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Place
        fields = ('id', 'coordinates', 'type')

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer( )
    place = PlaceSerializer()
    devices = DeviceSerializer( many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'params', 'config',
                  'user', 'place', 'devices', 'created_at')
        depth=8

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # get principal fields
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        **place_data = validated_data.pop('place')**
        devices_data = validated_data.pop('devices')

        # get nested fields

        # devices nested fields
        devices = []
        for device in devices_data:
            places = []
            places_data = device.pop('places')
            for place in places_data:
                places.append( **Place(coordinates=place['coordinates'], type=place['type'])** )

            device['places'] = places
            devices.append( Device.objects.create(**device) )
        validated_data['devices'] = devices
        # user nested fields
        institute_data = user_data.pop('institute')
        place = institute_data.pop('place')
        institute_data['place'] = Place(coordinates=place['coordinates'], type=place['type'])
        user_data['institute'] = Institute.objects.create(**institute_data)
        validated_data['user'] = User.objects.create(**user_data)
        profile = Profile.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return profile
```

I've defined PlaceSerializer on many ways but all of them gets the same result, Below describe this ways

CASE 1

```
class PlaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    coordinates = serializers.ListSerializer(
        child=serializers.FloatField(),
    )
```

CASE 2

```
class CoordinatesSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
        child=serializers.FloatField()

class PlaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    coordinates = CoordinatesSerializer()
```

CASE 3

```
class PlaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    coordinates = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.FloatField()
    )
```

CASE 4

```
class PlaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    coordinates = serializers.ListField()
```

CASE 5

```
class PlaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    coordinates = serializers.ListSerializer()
#gives error for child is not present
```

I had changed the types, CharField, IntegerField, FloatField, etc with same results.

Another tests that I've done are append to serializer the methods create, update, to_representation, to_internal_value, all of this for to manage in a better way the info that will saved o retrieved but any works. Another curiosity, if I add a simple Listfield like [10,90,1], is saved and retrieved without problem in contrast when this ListField is inside Place Objects

Please if you know how to solve this I'll glad to you.

Comment: Any updates to the problem? Has it been fixed?

Comment: nop, i had change my DB structure because DRF sucks on this case, that new structure is not useful but it works for the moment